# Slice only working on the last line in a file using 'with open' and 'readline'

Tags: loops, python-2.7, readline, slice

What I am trying to accomplish:  Pull the last 8 characters from the lines in a file, slice them into two character chunks, compare those chunks with my dictionary, and list the results.  This is literally the first thing I have done in python, and my head is spinning with all the answers here.
I think I need basic swimming instruction, and every answer seems to be a primer on free-diving for world records.

I am using the following code (Right now I have the h1 through h4 commented out because it is not returning keys that are in my dictionary):

```
d1 = {'30': 0, '31': 1, '32': 2, '33' : 3, '34': 4, '35': 5, '36': 6, '37': 7,  '38':  8, '39': 9,
  '41': 'A', '42': 'B', '43': 'C', '44': 'D', '45': 'E', '46': 'F'}



filename = raw_input("Filename? > ")

with open(filename) as file:

for line in iter(file.readline, ''):
    h1 = line[-8:-6]
    h2 = line[-6:-4]
    h3 = line[-4:-2]
    h4 = line[-2:]


    #h1 = d1[h1]
    #h2 = d1[h2]
    #h3 = d1[h3]
    #h4 = d1[h4]

    print h1,h2,h3,h4
```

Here is part of the txt file I am using as input:

naa.60000970000192600748533031453442
naa.60000970000192600748533031453342
naa.60000970000192600748533031453242
naa.60000970000192600748533031453142
naa.60000970000192600748533031434442
naa.60000970000192600748533031434342
naa.60000970000192600748533031434242
naa.60000970000192600748533032363342

When I run my script, here is the output generated by the code above:

14 53 44 2

14 53 34 2

14 53 24 2

14 53 14 2

14 34 44 2

14 34 34 2

14 34 24 2

32 36 33 42

The last line looks exactly as  I would expect.  All the other lines have been shifted or have dropped characters.  I am at a loss for this...I have tried many different ways to open the file in python, but have been unable to get them to loop through, or had other issues.

Is there a simple fix I am just missing here?   Thanks, j

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that what's going on is that each line you read has a carriage return at the end, except the last one.  So the last one is right, but the others are basically splitting the last part of the string.  IOW, I think your file lines look something like

```
>>> open("demo.txt").readline()
'naa.60000970000192600748533031453442\n'
```

where the `\n` is the symbol for the carriage return, and is only one character (it's not `\` + `n`).  I might write your code something like

```
with open(filename) as myfile:
    for line in myfile:
        line = line.strip() # get rid of leading and trailing whitespace

        h1 = line[-8:-6]
        h2 = line[-6:-4]
        h3 = line[-4:-2]
        h4 = line[-2:]

        print h1,h2,h3,h4
```

which for me produces

```
Filename? > demo.txt
31 45 34 42
31 45 33 42
31 45 32 42
31 45 31 42
31 43 44 42
31 43 43 42
31 43 42 42
32 36 33 42
```

We could simplify the `h` parts, but we'll leave that alone for now.  :^)

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thanks DSM.
My output now appears as this (I put the h1 - 4 back in):

Filename? > luns.txt
3 4 9 0
3 4 A 0
3 4 B 0
...

One last thing....is there an easy way to remove the spaces between the 4 results?   I am currently printing them with this statement:
    print h1,h2,h3,h4
I tried h1 + h2 + h3 + h4 but it adds the numbers up, not just prints them next to each other.

Comment: Actually figured it out just now:              
    print "VM ID ---- %s   VMAX Lun---" % line,
    print '%s%s%s%s' % (h1,h2,h3,h4)



VM ID ---- naa.60000970000192600748533031453142   VMAX Lun--- 1E1B